# Using multiple date ranges in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to grab the following date ranges:

- Current date - prior 6 weeks
- 51 weeks ago - 55  weeks ago

I have the following query, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
OR date(date) >= date(dateadd(week,-6, current_date))
OR date(date) >= date(dateadd(week,-55, current_date))
OR date(date) <= date(dateadd(week,-51, current_date))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use AND for specifying the date range. Try the following where condition.

```sql
date(date) >= date(dateadd(week,-6, current_date))
OR (
  date(date) >= date(dateadd(week,-55, current_date))
  AND
  date(date) <= date(dateadd(week,-51, current_date))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use date arithmetics:

```
select *
from the_table
where the_date_column <= current_date - interval '6 week'
   or the_date_column between 
                           current_date - interval '55 week' 
                      and  current_date - interval '51 week';
```

If `the_date_column` is actually a `timestamp` column (not a `date` column) you might want to cast it to a `date` to get rid of the time part using `the_date_column::date`

The manual explains all available date/time functions: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: So I'm actually using Amazon Redshift. Does this change everything?

Comment: @user3456571: no idea, I have never used redshift and I don't know on which Postgres version this is based. But date artithmetics has been like that for ages (as a matter of fact this is pretty much standard SQL except for the "week" interval). You should have added that to your initial question.